# Regular Expression (match word + some number) C#

Tags: c#, regex

Sorry doing this the fast way of asking all the regex experts out there :)

What regex for C# can I use that matches the end of a word + some number

Eg.  End of string matches with "Story" + 0 or more numbers

```
"ThisIsStory1"    = true
"ThisIsStory2000" = true
"ThisIsStory"     = true
"Story1IsThis"    = false
"IsStoryThis1"    = false
```

Hope this makes sense

A regular expression that I could plug into C# would be fantastic.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for admitting this is the fast way :)

Answer (score 8):

You'll need something like this `Story[0-9]*$`

So it matches for story (ignoring anything before it, you may need to add more), then for 0 or more numbers between story and the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Try `[A-Za-z]*Story[0-9]*`.

If you want to check against a whole line, `^[A-Za-z]*Story[0-9]*$`.

Comment: I don't know C#-specific regex, but I know in other languages, `?` means "zero or one"; "zero or more" would be `*`.

Comment: It also isn't matching the end of the string so FirstStory123MoreStory would return true when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

to match number of characters before story and then story???? use this:

```
"[A-Za-z]*(s|S)tory\d*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string compare = "story1withANumber";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]+Story[0-9]*");

if (regex.IsMatch(compare))
{ 
    //true
}

regex = new Regex("[0-9]");

if (regex.IsMatch(compare))
{ 
    //true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A .NET regex that meets your criteria is:

```
Story\d*\b
```

(Use the Regex.IgnoreCase option if desired.)

`\b` matches the word boundary, so `Story1IsThis` will not match, but `ThisIsAStory1` will.  The word 'Story' does not need to end the string, so the string `"ThisIsAStory234 ThisIsNot"` will match on `Story234`.